Confused about timeout for trstringer/manual-approval GitHub Action
The documentation mentions...

Note: This approval duration is subject to the broader 72 hours
timeout for a workflow. So keep that in mind when figuring out how
quickly an approver must respond.

Then a little further down it states...

A job (including a paused job) will be failed after 6 hours

I find the above two statements to be incredibly confusing. How long would someone have to approve, 72 hours or 6 hours? What is the difference between the two timeouts? Can I get a little more detail on what scenarios define each?

I could not find an official GitHub source about 72 hours for workflow execution.
GitHub documentation says

Workflow run time - Each workflow run is limited to 35 days. If a workflow run reaches this limit, the workflow run is cancelled. This period includes execution duration, and time spent on waiting and approval.

The same source says that a GitHub-hosted runner can not run longer than 6 hours, effectively limiting how long a job can consumer compute resource. However, when a job is waiting for a manual approval it does not consume compute. A runner is started once approval is received.
Self-hosted runners can have longer execution times. However, job execution has its own timeout set by the workflow itself. Its default is 360 minutes. This timeout can be increased. See here
I read the above as giving an approver up to 35 days to approve a job waiting on an environment manual approval deployment protection rule.
On top of this, if a job is using a default GITHUB_TOKEN, this token expiration will limit maximum job execution because the token is only valid for 24 hours. This token timeout can not be configured.
